# Backwards target OS deployment puzzle

Tags: deployment, target

[image]I recompiled my completed app so that it will run on OS 10.9, however when I try to open it in OSX 10.14.6 (Mojave), I get the contradictory panel warning: "You have macOS 10.9. The application requires macOS 10.14 or later." I double-checked the app's info plist file and it shows the target to be 10.9 as it should. What gives here?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a work-around. I upgraded my OS to Catalina 10.15.7 so that a downloaded copy of XCode 8.15 would run. Within this framework I was able to generate my app targeted for OS 10.9 that was kosher for Catalina. I suppose that the self-contradictory warnings when I tried to copy my older app onto OS Mojave had something to do with the lack of a code-signature, for I am still in the development phase of production and do not have a mac developer signature yet. However since this is not a full solution to my question, I am withholding bonus points from being awarded to myself.